# iOS - How to detect if two or more objects collide

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, collision

How can i detect if two or more objects collide?
I would like to use only default frameworks, such Core Graphics. Or i have to use Box2d or Cocos2d?

EDIT
You're right, the question isn't really clear.
So this is the situation : 
i have multiple UIImageView which move with the accelerometer, but i want that when two or more images collides these isn't overlap each others. Is it clear?

Comment: This is incredibly vague.  We would need to know what data structures are being used to represent the objects, and then we'd need to know what sort of space (1D, 2D, 3D?) the objects are in.  You don't *need* any specific framework, although they're often helpful. Googling for `collision detection` and doing some reading would be a good way to get some background before coming back and rephrasing this question.

Comment: I use UIImageView objects if this can be helpful

Comment: Do you want to use pixel perfect detection? If so, that can be quite hard.

Comment: No, i don't need it is perfect, i need the logic of the things. The images have to "lean" each others, only to give the "effect"

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want a multi-step process.

First, define a "center" and "radius" for each object, such that a line drawn around the center at the selected radius will entirely encompass the object without "too much extra".  (You define how hard you work to define center and radius to prevent "too much".)

An optional next step is to divide the screen into quadrants/sections somehow, and compute which objects (based on their centers and radii) lie entirely within one quadrant, which straddle a quadrant boundary, which straddle 4 quadrants, etc.  This allows you to subset the next step and only consider object pairs that are in the same quadrant or where one of the two is a straddler of one sort or another.

Then, between every pair of objects, calculate the center-to-center distance using the Pythagorean theorem.  If that distance is less than the sum of the two objects' radii then you have a potential collision.

Finally, you have to get down and dirty with calculating actual collisions.  There are several different approaches, depending on the shape of your objects.  Obviously, circles are covered by the prior step, squares/rectangles (aligned to the X/Y axes) can be computed fairly well, but odd shapes are harder.  One scheme is to, on a pair of "blank" canvases, draw the two objects, then AND together the two, pixel by pixel, to see if you come up with a 1 anywhere.  There are several variations of this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your question is pretty vague, and therefore difficult to answer succinctly.  But to give you some ideas to go by, you can do this with core animation, though some 3rd party gaming engines/frameworks may be more efficient.

Essentially, you create a timer that fires quite often (how often would depend on the size of the objects you're colliding and their speed - too slow and the objects can collide and pass each other before the timer fires - math is your friend here).

Every time the timer fires you check each object on screen for collisions with the others.  For efficiencies sake you should ensure that you only check each pair once - ie. if you have A,B,C,D objects, check A & D but not D & A.

If you have a collision handle it however you want (animation/points/notification/whatever you want to do).

There's way too much to cover here in a post.  I'd suggest checking out the excellent writeup on the Asteroids game at cocoawithlove, especially part 3 (though not iOS the principles are the same):
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/asteroids-style-game-in-coreanimation.html